# Hows does a processor physically do calculations?

Tags: microprocessor, computer-architecture

What should I know to understand how a processor performs computations, at the level of the electron (concerning adders,gates,etc.)?

Suppose I already know the logic side of the issue, i.d. how processors do arithmetic by binary logic operations.

I need an overview of the main subjects, perhaps in the form of a diagram.

Comment: There are too many layers between the calculations and the electrons. These are covered under somewhat complete Electrical Engineering university degree program...

Comment: I understand there is a lot going on in there, but can you give an overview? I mean lets say we want to calculate two plus two. What happens, generally?

Comment: What a broad question..

Comment: Its no braoder than some of the other questions, here. It shouldn't be hard to give an overview.

Comment: Try to watch this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wvJc9CZcvBc

Comment: When you say "How does a processor do math phsyically, as in what happens to the electrons", do you mean "how do semiconductors work" or "how do I go from if-then-else to voltages and currents"

Comment: This is like asking how coal leads to a shirt... We can't explain from steam engines to eccentric gears to cotton mills to weave to clothing design to - you get the idea. Research on your own, there's vast explanations out there, you can find them.

Comment: Obviously I can't find them. All the articles just say broad things like the core does arithmetic etc.

Comment: That's because that is what a core does. In digital design, abstraction needs to be made. It's impossible to talk about the low level at all times. We use math and programming languages/HDL to go to building blocks like cores, memories, etc which are made up of ALUs, control structures, etc which are made up of adders and multipliers etc which are built up of individual gates which are built up out of transistors. Any decent digital design book will cover this in an introduction

Comment: Im a programmer for a living, I know how the software part works, but was looking for more in depth explanations of how an adder circuit would work.

Comment: 1+1 =0 with carry bit , is one possible combination , expand this then you can subtract, by 2's complement then multiply/ divide by shifts and more to xxx powers of 10 with floating point

Comment: It's possible to describe an adder at gate level. But to transistor level it won't make sense. Maybe you should learn how gate works at transistor level, then a adder at gate level. After you've learned all the basic components (adder, registers, decoder, etc) at gate level, you can understand a CPU core at RTL level. After that it's instructions and programming languages. It's always to use one level lower abstraction to explain the next higher level. Talking how the lowest level implements the highest level is impossible.

Comment: Even in programming asking how 3D game is working in terms of low level assembly instructions makes a little sense. Yet there are much less abstraction layers in between.

Comment: start with schematic for CMOS adder then work yer way up slowly up to an ALU. Google "images " will express more than 1000 words

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/Code-Language-Computer-Developer-Practices-ebook/dp/B00JDMPOK2

Answer (score 1):

There's basically two concepts you'll have to explore.

First, how does the digital logic work? Using logic gates, you can basically build up whatever mathematical logic engine you want (theoretically). This rough generalization won't really change, but in the future we may have more than just binary logic (1 and 0).

Second, how do those gates actually operate from a analog physics standpoint? This is basically the IEEE article, etc. This will potentially change with time, too.

It'll be difficult to find one source that puts it all together (outside of a textbook) because they are different EE fields of study.

Comment: Thank you, is there any way you can make a diagram of a simple addition problem?

Comment: @Nirelan: do a google search for "binary adder" - you'll get links to many descriptions of adders - Wikipedia has a long article.  These should answer some of your questions.

Comment: Thank you Peter, I found http://improve.dk/adding-67-at-the-logic-gate-level/ and it seems to do a good job of breaking it down. Is there anything you would add to that?

Comment: Btw, I wanted to thank @PeterBennett and @G36! Until I found that article that specifically mentioned the carry part, it was confusing. I was more specific about my searches thanks to you and explaining how the carry works made it make sense.